# Economics article on BitCoin

Tags: economic-theory, academic-research

I was wondering if some economists started to create a research group around BitCoin, or published academic paper on it. In general, I was wondering how BitCoin was analyzed and studied in academic research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, it seems, most of Bitcoin-related published research are of technical and legal nature (according to [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.ru/scholar?q=bitcoin&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5), [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/research-papers/search/?query=bitcoin), [Bitcoin Wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Research)). 
While there is some economical analysis performed by community ([wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Category:Economics), [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/588/2343)), I haven't managed to find any papers in peer-reviewed journals.

[This discission](http://www.quora.com/Bitcoin/Why-isnt-Bitcoin-interesting-to-leading-economists?share=1) on Quora explains some of possible reasons for this. Excerpt from top answer by Erik Madsen:

> Overall, Bitcoin is a fine example of a currency market, but it hasn’t
>   (so far) told economists anything new about how the world works. It’s
>   not surprising that most research on Bitcoin is from a cryptography
>   standpoint, because that’s really the interesting part of the whole
>   endeavor.

and his comment on another answer:

> Private currencies are no longer common, but they have existed.  And
>   the intentional opaqueness of the market, and it IS quite opaque,
>   means that its utility as a data source is severely limited.